# t-stat for feature selection

Tags: r, machine-learning, t-test, feature-selection

I want to calculate  t-Statistic for feature selection in R with for loop. Data has 155 columns and dependent variable is binary (mutagen - nonmutagen). I would like to assign a t-stat for every columns. The problem is I couldn't figure out how can I write it.

Here is the formula I'm trying to implement in R:

[image]

Also I wrote a code but I'm not sure about it and it's just for first column. I need to write it in for loop for all columns.

```
abs(diff(tapply(train_df[,1], train_df$Activity, mean))) / sqrt(sd((train_df$NEG_01_NEG[train_df$Activity == "mutagen"])^2) / (length(train_df$NEG_01_NEG[train_df$Activity == "mutagen"])) + 
   sd((train_df$NEG_01_NEG[train_df$Activity != "mutagen"])^2) / (length(train_df$NEG_01_NEG[train_df$Activity != "mutagen"])))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, asking for help with coding is off topic here. Second, why do you want to do feature selection using a $t$-statistic? I do not know any goal (such as predictive modelling, explanatory modelling, ...) for which this kind of selection would be optimal. Consider lasso (and its versions), ridge regression or elastic net instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy First I didn't know that, sorry. I'm just trying to get a priori knowledge before the train a model. I'm not looking for optimal selection or something like that. I just saw a feature selection method on a paper and wanted to try it.That's all. Btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have a function that does exactly that but that doesn't help you much if want to do the coding yourself. Let me know if you want that

Comment: @ekstroem it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about speed (and with 155 columns you probably don't care) you can use the `t.test` function and apply it to every column.

Simulate some data first

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(y=rep(1:2, 50), x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100), x3=rnorm(100))
head(DF)

  y         x1          x2         x3
1 1 -0.6264538 -0.62036668  0.4094018
2 2  0.1836433  0.04211587  1.6888733
3 1 -0.8356286 -0.91092165  1.5865884
4 2  1.5952808  0.15802877 -0.3309078
5 1  0.3295078 -0.65458464 -2.2852355
6 2 -0.8204684  1.76728727  2.4976616
```

Then we can apply the `t.test` function to all but the first column using the formula argument.

```
group <- DF$y
lapply(DF[,-1], function(x) { t.test(x ~ group)$statistic })
```

which returns the test statistic for each column.

`t.test` computes a lot of extra information that you don't need so you can speed this up substantially by doing the computations directly, but it really isn't necessary here

Comment: Probably this is the fastest and easiest way to calculate t-score for data frame. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it works for you then please accept the answer. I'm sure it's not the fastest, but probably not something you'll notice with most datasets